# See G-code before exporting

Tags: slicing, slic3r

When using Slic3r I noticed that `Slice now` and `Export G-Code` do different things. While `Slice now` is nice, it does not show any tool paths etc.

Is there an actual way to generate and visualize the G-code in Slic3r without saving the exported G-Code first? When aligning seams etc., it is quite annoying to always save the file to see a difference because `Slice now` seems to make little difference.

Answer (score 1):

Using Repetier Host V2.1.2 and slicing with Slic3r (or with CuraEngine), there is an "edit Gcode" button under the Print Preview tab.  It is located at the top right of the screen.  With that button you can access, examine and change the Gcode of the project you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

After you use the Slice Now button (and the slicing progress bar shows completed), select the preview tab. To the right of the window you will see a pair of vertical sliders. Each slider changes the start and finish locations for the filament layers.

You can slide the left one to the bottom, which will "empty" the virtual print bed. Each movement upward will display a succeeding layer, showing the placement of the filament. This ostensibly will present to you alignment information as well as unexpected holes or other failure points.

I don't know of any slicer that lacks a preview. That doesn't mean one does not exist, but why would such a useful feature be omitted?

Comment: Have you saved the g code and then watched the preview again? It then changes from those simple slicing preview to the detailed one where you see the seams, different extrusions, duration, head movement etc. This is what I am looking for. Not only layer by layer preview but also retraction, flow etc just without always the need to save the g code